# fast-fps-mode in Android Camera.Parmaters - how to access and alter?

Tags: java, android, parameters, camera, frame-rate

When dumping Android Camera.Parameters I've noticed a parameter called fast-fps-mode=0.

Does anyone have any information on how this parameter is altered?

It doesn't appear to be mentioned in any documentation that I can find. Ideally I'm trying to improve my frame rate, more ideally set a constant frame rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of undocumented device-specific parameters. Android camera design allows infinite number of these. These parameters are defined by device manufacturer, and aren't standardized. They even may change after a minor system upgrade. If you don't have sources for you're camera HAL, you are limited to trial-and-error reverse engineering the subtle interdependencies between undocumented parameters: *which FPS is available when `fast-fps-mode=1`?* and what are the accepted values of `fast-fps-mode`?

Using wrong set of parameters, you will likely catch a RuntimeException when you finally call `Camera.setParameters()`. But this is not guaranteed. Some devices will silently ignore unsupported parameters, or change them on their own accord, or whatever.

Usually, you can choose one of the [supported preview FPS ranges](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewFpsRange()) with fixed FPS, often `"(15000-15000)"` or `"(30000-30000)"`.

Comment: Sorry Alex, am new to the site so unfortunately cannot upvote the response. Will make sure I come back and do when I can :)

Comment: You can accept an answer, though. This will also improve your reputation ;-)